# How do I retrieve a list of employees that have 5 specific traits?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `EmpTraits` with a list of employees and their traits. So this table will list each employee and all of their traits (employee can be listed multiple times as long as the trait is different, so this table doesn't have 2 records with same employee and same trait).

```
`Table: EmpTraits
+------------+---------+
 | EmployeeID | TraitID |
 +------------+---------+`
```

Let's say I have a VIEW called `EmpXTraits` (Employee X Traits) which just lists all the traits Employee X has (which is a total of 5).

```
`Table: EmpXTraits
+------------+---------+
 | EmployeeID | TraitID |
 +------------+---------+
 |     X      +    1    +
 |     X      +    2    +
 |     X      +    3    +
 |     X      +    4    +
 |     X      +    5    +
 +------------+---------+`
```

From these two tables, I'm trying to query a list of all EmployeeIDs that have all of the traits shown in the VIEW `EmpXTraits`.

I have the following query so far, but the problem is that is shows employees that have the exact same traits as employee X. So if another employee has all those similar traits and more, he would not show up.

```
`
SELECT DISTINCT EmpTraits.EmployeeID
FROM   EmpTraits INNER JOIN EmpXTraits ON 
       EmpTraits.EmployeeID = EmpXTraits.EmployeeID
WHERE  EmpTraits.TraitID IN (
       SELECT EmployeeID 
       FROM EmpXTraits
);`
```

Any ideas how I can change this query to show all employees who have **at least** the traits from employee X (they can have more traits as long as they have all traits that employee X has).

Thank you!!

Comment: The relational operator you require is known as [relational division](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following. (No need to know before hand how many traits are in EmpXTraits)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ee.EmployeeID
  FROM EmpTraits AS ee
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT x.TraitID FROM EmpXTraits AS x 
                   EXCEPT 
                   SELECT e.TraitID FROM EmpTraits AS e 
                    WHERE e.EmployeeID = ee.EmployeeID);
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked just as I expected. I wasn't aware of the EXCEPT function until now, so thank you for that as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT EmpTraits.EmployeeID, Count(EmpTraits.TraitID)
FROM   EmpTraits 
INNER JOIN EmpXTraits ON EmpTraits.EmployeeID = EmpXTraits.EmployeeID
Group BY EmpTraits.EmployeeID
Having Count(EmpTraits.TraitID) > 4
```

I think this will do the trick.

Comment: Mister Positive, unfortunately this doesn't work as I expected. wdosanjos provided a great solution that worked.